# Sitecore WFFM, how to create separate "To" email address for languages

Tags: forms, sitecore, multilingual, web-forms-for-marketers

We have a form created and the send email action is created for when they click submit.  After that, when I click the send email action a modal window opens where I can set the "To" and "From" email addresses.

Our issue is this, we have a client that is global.  They want the form to use different languages.  But for some reason the send email action does not allow for language versions.  If I set it for English US, then go into french, it will have the same "To" email address for all of those.

Is there a way to have this field change per language culture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We raised this with Sitecore support in the past (Ticket 412571). They acknowledged the issue but said the following;

> Save Actions are not designed for multilingual setup. Each used action
>   from Save Actions is stored in a Form item in the Save Actions field,
>   which is marked as Shared and Unversioned. That’s why, you can’t add a
>   language version to your Send Mail action. We recommend using the
>   Email Campaign Manager for sending out emails in different languages.

So it would seem that your best bet is to start using ECM